# regular expression in Ruby: check the total number of digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a one line gsub to replace all the non-digits in a string but only if the non-digits are not more than three and if the total length of the digits is 10

I have this which fits the first condition

```
p "0177/385490".gsub(/((\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+))/,'\2\3\4\5') 
#=>"0177385490"
```

but when i try this the {10} check doesn't work

```
p "0177/385490".gsub(/((\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+)){10}/,'\2\3\4\5') 
#=>"0177/385490"
```

how to do this please ?

EDIT

i managed to to it like this, but how to do this in a oneline gsub ?

```
strings = [
   "0473/385 490",
   "0473/385490",
   "0473 38 54 90",
   "0473/385 4901"    #this one is't captured
 ]

 strings.each do |s|
   if /((\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+))/ =~ s
     if "#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}#{$5}".length == 10
       puts "#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}#{$5}"
     end
   end
 end
```

EDIT: to show why it really needs to be a onle line gsub here my routine, there will be more replacements added

```
def cleanup text
  replacements = [
     {:pattern => /(04\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})/, :replace_with => '\1\2\3\4'},
     {:pattern => /(0\d)(\/| |-)(\d{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})/, :replace_with => '\1\3\4\5'},
     {:pattern => /(\d{6} )(\d{3})-(\d{2})/, :replace_with => '\1\2 \3'},
     {:pattern => /(\d{2,4})\D?(\d{2,3})\D?(\d{2,3})/, :replace_with => '\1\2\3'}
  ].each{|replacement|text.gsub!(replacement[:pattern], replacement[:replace_with])}
  text
end
```

Comment: Why do you *need* a one-liner, and why does it *need* to use `gsub`?

Comment: i do a series of replacements which are put in an array, each time the searchpattern and the replacementpattern, this needs to be added to that array

Comment: You should consider implementing each processing step as a method instead, and using an array of method names, so that some other programmer (or yourself in 6 months) can get at least a hint of what is going on.

Comment: tens of methods each doing the same thing ? sorry but that is not efficient, i use this little routine in all script that do mupltiple regex replacements, all i have to do is adjust the search and replace patterns and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone but i can't use the answers because i can't insert them in my routine (edited my answer to make that more clear). Found a sollution myself. I give everyone an upvote who had a one line solution as requested, now i still need to find a way to insert my block as a replacementpattern in the cleanup routine

```
p "0177/3854901".gsub(/(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+)/){ |m| "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}".length==10 ? "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}":m} 
#=> "0177/3854901" isn't replaced because it has 11 digits
p "0177/385490".gsub(/(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+)/){ |m| "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}".length==10 ? "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}":m} 
#=> "0177385490"
```

Comment: I fail to see how that handles `but only if the non-digits are not more than three`.

Comment: simple, \D? stands for only one non-digit (they may not succeed each other), so if a fourth non-digit is there the replacement is not made, try it

Comment: I see. Still, your definition said nothing about `0aaa123456789` being invalid. Also `still0a1b2c3456789here` will be partially replaced.

Comment: you'r right, thanks for pointing that out, must be sparated from other text with \b So .gsub(/\b(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?(\d+)\D?+(\d+)\b/){ |m| "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}".length==10 ? "#{$1}#{$2}#{$3}#{$4}":m} it will be

Answer (score 3):

I think a one-line `gsub` wouldn't be overly readable. Here's my approach:

```
chars, non_chars = s.each_char.partition { |c| c =~ /\d/ }
puts chars.join if chars.size == 10 && non_chars.size <= 3
```

Clean and easy to read, without any magic variables. Plus it clearly shows the rules you have imposed on the string.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner with gsub, mostly to illustrate why Michael Kohl's approach is better:

```
(digits = s.gsub(/\D/, '')).length == 10 && s.length < 14 ? digits : s
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

```
puts s.gsub(/\D/, '') if (/\A(\d\D?){10}\z/ =~ s) && (/\A(\d+\D){0,3}\d*\z/ =~ s)
```

Comment: This doesn't check whether there are more than 3 non-digits in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to know about the `scan` method.

```
strings.each do |s|
  numbers = s.scan(/\d/).join
  non_numbers = s.scan(/\D/)
  puts numbers if numbers.length == 10 && non_numbers.length < 4
end
```

But I like the solution by @MichaelKohl better.

And then a silly example:

```
strings.select{|s| s.scan(/\D/).length < 4}.map{|s| s.scan(/\d/).join}.select{|s| s.length==10}
```